# Vim replacing linefeeds

Tags: vim

I resisted Vim, but have now given in. It works large files like a hot knife through butter.

Situation: I have a large text file, I want to put a pipe character at the beginning and ending of each line.

Problem: These Vims and other variations didn't work:

```
:%s/$/|\$|
:%s/\r/|\r|
:%s/$/|\r|
```

I suspect it's something simple to fix this, but searching Google and Stack didn't help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You nearly had it:

```
:%s/^\|$/|/g
```

`^\|$` means *beginning or end of line*.  In a Vim regex, the `|` "or" pipe gets escaped. That is followed by `/|/g` -- *replace with `|` globally*.

Comment: Thank you Michael.  The command worked perfectly.  ..and your additional comments about why the command worked were very helpful. I had a feeling the pipe may need escaping.

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I'd prefer the expressiveness of *'surround each line with pipe chars'*:

```
:%s/.*/|&|
```

This, in my brain, is more intuitive than *'replace a non-existing, imaginary character at the start or end of a line'*.

It also depends on fewer magic chars (`^`,`$`, quoted `\|` which are all clumsy to type and error prone. (I mean, do you remember to quote the regex `|`? Do you know the difference between `$` and `\_$`? Did you know some, if not all, of these depend on the 'magic configuration' of vim?)).

The above suffers from none of those.

Comment: It took me a day to think about this. Interesting. I like your answer also. Good God.. more than one good answer ;) Your command has perfect results also. I'm not knowledge-able enough at this point to know which is better.